# Invoke a managed bean method before render-response phase

Tags: jsf

JSF version I using is 1.2_09. RichFaces API is 3.3.2.SR1.

I'm using `<rich:dataTable>` component to render a List into a table. Let I've a manage-bean method which initialize a mange-bean property. The method will be invoked when the `get(int)` List mehtod is invoked to render the data. For instance, the method:

```
String orderedProperty;
// Something else
protected String parseOrderGetParameter(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String orderedProperty = "";
        Map<String, String[]> params = (Map<String, String[]>) request.getParameterMap();
        String[] value = params.get("fsp");

        if(value == null){
            return orderedProperty;
        }

        for(String s : params.get("fsp")){
            orderedProperty = orderedProperty.concat(s); 
        }

        String[] parts = orderedProperty.split(":");
        orderedProperty = parts[2];
        orderedProperty = orderedProperty.replaceFirst("j_id", "");
        orderedProperty = getHeaderNameById(Integer.valueOf(orderedProperty));
        return orderedProperty;
    }
```

Is there a way to invoke a maange bean method before the render-response phase?

Comment: Best answer depends on JSF version. This information is however missing in your question. Please always mention the library impl/version in **every** question.

Comment: @BalusC I've added JSF version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JSF 1.2, your best bet is the `<f:view beforePhase>` hook.

```html
<f:view beforePhase="#{bean.beforePhase}">
    ...
</f:view>
```

```java
public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    if (event.getPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
        // Do here your job which should run right before the RENDER_RESPONSE.
    }
}
```

---

In case you're using JSF 2.0/2.1, use `<f:event type="preRenderView">`, or if you're using JSF 2.2, use `<f:viewAction>`.

Comment: One more clarification. Can I get actual `HttpServletRequest` object inside the `beforePhase` method body?

Comment: Just grab the request parameters from `FacesContext` the usual way: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()`. Having `javax.servlet.*` imports in a JSF backing bean class is a red flag, so whenever you stumble upon this, look in `FacesContext` and `ExternalContext` first.

Comment: I mean if I grab the request from `FacesContext` in the usual way whether I get actual `RequestParameter Map` which is passed to the server?

Comment: I've understood you. Thank you.

Comment: Must dataTable be stated inside <f:view>?

Comment: I doesn't work. I put `<f:view beforePhase="#controller.beforePhase()}"> </f:view>` inside my `<ui:composition>` tag. And that method doesn't invoke. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: I mean `<f:view beforePhase="#controller.beforePhase}"> </f:view>`. It was a typo.

Comment: `<ui:composition>`? Is it a template client or an include file? If template client, it should be in turn in `<ui:define>`.